# The function passed to MapPartitions is called 8 times in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, databricks

I am new to Spark and Databricks. I noticed that I have more logs than I expect. I investigated the problem and narrowed down to a particular issue:

```
def func_1(*args, **kwargs):
     print("some work here")
     yield [Row('field1', 'field2')(1, 2)]

test_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
testRDD = sc.parallelize(test_list, 1)
resultRDD  = testRDD.mapPartitions(func_1, 1)
resultsDF = spark.createDataFrame(resultRDD.flatMap(lambda x: x), schema=someSchema) 
resultsDF.collect()
sdf = sdf.union(resultsDF)
print(sdf.count())
```

The `sdf.count()` is fine, it returns 1. The problem is that `func_1` is being called 8 times for some reason.

Could someone help me investigate this furthermore?

Comment: can you show all code including your someSchema pls?

Comment: @thebluephantom unfortunately, the project is a commercial one, so all the details are under NDA. 
But as I pointed in the question, the problem was narrowed to this part of the code.
Do you think the schema could be the problem here?

Comment: No, but it is handy to provide code that works to answer the question...